# ¿Como puedo actualizar data relacionada con Entity Framework Core 2.1?

Tags: entity-framework-core

estoy intentando actualizar unos registros de mi entidad **User**, ésta tiene un par de llaves foráneas y también quiero que se actualicen esos registros pero no así un campo de mi entidad principal que es **User**, de manera que:

Mi modelo es:

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ProfileId { get; set; }
    public int UserTypeId { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Skype { get; set; }
    public int SalutationId { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DateModified { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }

    public List<Email> Emails { get; set; }
    public List<Phone> Phones { get; set; }        
    public List<UserCenter> UserCenter { get; set; }        
}
```

Y lo intento actualizar así:

```
 private void UpdateUser(User user)
 {
      user.DateModified = DateTime.Now;

      using (var context = new LCDPContext())
      {
          var input = context.Attach(user);

          input.Property(p => p.Username).IsModified = true;
          input.Property(p => p.SalutationId).IsModified = true;
          input.Property(p => p.Active).IsModified = true;
          input.Property(p => p.FirstName).IsModified = true;
          input.Property(p => p.LastName).IsModified = true;
          input.Property(p => p.Skype).IsModified = true;
          input.Property(p => p.Password).IsModified = true;
          input.Property(p => p.UserTypeId).IsModified = true;
          input.Property(p => p.ProfileId).IsModified = true;
          input.Property(p => p.DateModified).IsModified = true;              

          context.SaveChanges();
      }
 }
```

No estoy indicando la propiedad **DateCreated** Pero no se como indicar que se actualice la data relacionada.